# Como puedo crear una expresion regular que valide una contraseña segura?

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, regex, spring-boot

Estoy desarrollando un programa con angular y spring boot, en el caso del frontend tengo una seccion donde un usuario nuevo se registra con datos comunes como nombre, telefono, correo, etc. asi como tambien una contraseña. Esta ultima necesita ser validada mediante un regex o expresion regular. Los requerimientos para la contraseña son los siguientes:

- Debe ser de al menos 8 posiciones, incluyendo caracteres alfanuméricos
- No debe contener la palabra IBM
- No debe contener más de dos caracteres iguales de manera consecutiva (p.e. 222,eee)
- No debe tener más de dos caracteres consecutivos numéricos o alfabeticos (p.e. 123,abc)
- Reconoce mayúsculas y minúsculas

Ya revise varios tutoriales sobre expresiones regulares pero no he logrado hacer que la expresion valide correctamente cada uno de los requerimientos.

Solo pude llegar a esto actualmente:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\Bibm)(?!$(.)\1){8,}/gmi
```

Les agradeceria si pudieran orientarme sobre como lograrlo

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 2):

Para este caso te recomiendo mas que buscar validar que todo esté correcto ir validando si hay errores, entonces si tienes un match en tu regex significa que algo  en el password es incorrecto.

> Debe ser de al menos 8 posiciones, incluyendo caracteres alfanuméricos

`^.{0,7}$` Nos aseguramos de que tenga mas de 8 caracteres y `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` aseguramos que todos sean alfanuméricos

> No debe contener la palabra IBM

`IBM` buscamos la palabra

> No debe contener más de dos caracteres iguales de manera consecutiva (p.e. 222,eee)

`(.)\1{2,}` con `(.)` colocamos en un grupo cualquier carácter `\1` es si es igual al primer grupo que se capturó y `{2,}` si se repite más de 2 veces

> No debe tener más de dos caracteres consecutivos numéricos o alfabéticos (p.e. 123,abc)

`[a-zA-Z]{3,}` `[0-9]{3,}` con eso vemos si hay 3 caracteres numéricos o alfabéticos juntos

La expresión completa sería `[^a-zA-Z0-9]|^.{0,7}$|IBM|(.)\1{2,}|[a-zA-Z]{3,}|[0-9]{3,}` usando el carácter `|` que en regex es básicamente un 'or', asi si nuestra expresión nos regresa un match sabemos que hay algún error en nuestro password y no es válido.

Como recomendación cuando tengas que trabajar con regex la página de [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) es muy buena ahi puedes ir probando y además te va diciendo exactamente que significa tu expresión. Aqui te dejo el [link](https://regex101.com/r/0W6h9S/1) ya con la regex escrita y un par de casos de pruebas para que los veas y puedas igual experimentar cambiando los valores, te ayudará mucho a entender exactamente como funciona

Answer (score 1):

Yo iría por una expresión que valide todo en un paso

**^(?!.*IBM)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*([a-z0-9])\1)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?¡"+,.:;='^|~_()¿{}[]\-])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?¡"+,.:;='^|~_()¿{}[]\-]{8,32}$**

(?!.*IBM) - que no contenga IBM si quieres que no distinga minúsculas/mayúsculas iría por hacer 2 validaciones separadas, no usar | sino literal dos validaciones

(?=.*[a-z]) - que contenga al menos una letra minúscula

(?=.*[A-Z]) - al menos una mayúscula

(?=.*\d) - al menos un dígito

(?!.*([a-z0-9])\1) - evitar números o letras consecutivos aa - AA - 11

(?=.*[#$@!%&*?¡"+,.:;='^|~_()¿{}[]\-]) - al menos un símbolo de estos

[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?¡"+,.:;='^|~_()¿{}[]\-] - caracteres permitidos en general

{8,32} - mínimo 8 caracteres máximo 32

evitar los números o letras secuenciales (1234 o abcd) si va estar muy difícil hacerlo con expresiones reculares, nunca lo he visto

Answer (score -1):

Yo realmente no me liaría con un regex, hay librerías que con enviarle como quieres de fuerte una password te devuelven true o false.

Por ejemplo la librería 'validator', tiene la función isStrongPassword donde le envías la password y un objecto con todo lo que quieres.

te dejo un [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-9q5tfa?file=index.js), el [link de la librería](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) y el [link de la función en concreto](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/blob/master/src/lib/isStrongPassword.js)